# Wedderburn-Artin decomposition of a group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If $C_3$ is the cyclic group of order $3$ (i.e., $C_3 = \operatorname{Span}\{g : g^3 = 1\}$), let $A = \mathbb{R}C_3$ be a group algebra. I want to decompose $A$ as direct product of $M_{n_i}(K_i)$, with $K_i$ subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, $n_i \geq 1$.

I know that $A$ is a semisimple ring (Maschke's Theorem), thus such a decomposition exists, by the Wedderburn-Artin theorem.

Now, following some suggestions, I've defined subrings $Ae$ and $Af$, with $e$ and $f$ idempotents given by
$$e = \frac{1}{3}(1 + t + t^2), \ f = 1 - e.$$
I've shown that $A \cong Ae \oplus Af$, and that $Af$ is a simple ring. However, I am stuck after this.

Since this is not a homework question, I see no problem in using different rings to illustrate how should I proceed.

Comment: Note that since cyclic groups are abelian, $A$ is a commutative ring. What does that imply for the $n_i$? Also, you got something wrong: the $K_i$ are not *subfields* of $\mathbb{R}$ but *field extensions*.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I finally tracked down the duplicate (which is essentially the same answer as I gave.)

Comment: I didn't realize it was a duplicate, sorry!